# Exception on InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I am calling a simple Java Class Test through a JSP Page.
This class Test will instantiate a IE with Selenium IE driver and search with Google.

```
package com.tcs;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import com.Utilities.GlobalConstance;

public class Test 
{
    public static void working()
    { 
        String fs = GlobalConstance.fileSeparator;
        File file = new File(GlobalConstance.getFrameWorkPath()+fs+fs+"other"+fs+fs+"IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle()); 

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

However , I am getting an exception like

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/AutoTester] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setup(InternetExplorerDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:51)
    at com.tcs.Test.working(Test.java:22)
    at org.apache.jsp.submitExecution_jsp._jspService(submitExecution_jsp.java:122)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please hlp.
REgards
Shweta

Comment: Where have you put the httpclient jar ?

Comment: Check whether you have Apache httpcore jar inside of the Silennium Web application WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: THanks shazin...I placed the jar...& its working now...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium-java-3.7.0 then make sure it should contain "httpcore-4.4.6.jar" file inside libs folder. If not then include it and import it in your project.